# Why can't my Apache see my media folder?

Tags: python, linux, django, apache, unix

```
Alias /media/ /home/matt/repos/hello/media
<Directory /home/matt/repos/hello/media>
Options -Indexes
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/matt/repos/hello/wsgi/django.wsgi
```

/media is my directory. When I go to mydomain.com/media/, it says 403 Forbidden. And, the rest of my site doesn't work because all static files are 404s. Why? The page loads. Just not the media folder.

Edit: hello is my project folder.
I have tried 777 all my permissions of that folder.

Comment: I think it is permissions problem. `chmod 666` on the folder and it should work properly.

Comment: nope, I have done chmod 777, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: However, it does work on my Django development server perfectly.

Comment: Isn't this a question for superuser.com?

Answer (score 4):

You have Indexes disabled, so Apache won't generate a listing of the files when you request the directory /media (instead, it shows the 403 Forbidden error).  Try accessing a file directly within there, e.g.: http://localhost/media/some_image.jpg

Comment: @alex: Do you actually have a file called `some_image.jpg` in `/home/matt/repos/hello/media`?

Comment: Yes, I do. And it's a 404. I'm guessing it's something to do with the Alias, since Apache accesses my page fine, and it loads. Only the static stuff is 404.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me that `WSGIScriptAlias / /home/matt/repos/hello/wsgi/django.wsgi` tells to apache that everything under / should be handled by the specified WSGI script. This also includes /media. You should tell apache to exclude /media from that rule.

Try adding this to your config file:

```
<LocationMatch "^/media/">
SetHandler None
</LocationMatch>
```

Or craft a regex that matches everything but files under /media and replace your WSGIScriptAlias line with this:

```
WSGIScriptAliasMatch <regex> /home/matt/repos/hello/wsgi/django.wsgi
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.  I missed a trailing slash. after media/

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves me correctly, Apache runs under it's own user account. Are you sure that this account has the correct permissions to that directory?

Comment: Yes. It accesses everything else fine. Just not that media folder.

Answer (score 0):

its all about the dash `Options -Indexes` 
and here is a complete editon to yours

```
 Alias /media/ /home/matt/repos/hello/media
<Directory "/home/matt/repos/hello/media">
    Options Indexes
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allowfrom all
</Directory
```

and i'd love to add

```
AllowOverride all
```

Feel free to delete it:)